# dom manipulation / event handlers didnt work

Tags: javascript, html

i'm still learning about this dom manipulation so i tried to make my button to have a shadow when you hover it.

here's html code

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm fixed-top" id="myNavbar">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupported" aria-controls="navbarSupported" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <a href="#" class="navbar-brand" id="hello">Navbar</a>
  <!-- Nav content -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupport">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link active">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">About</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">Inspiration</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto navbar-right">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">Create</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

here i tested if the dom manipulation is working or not so i tried to click my navbar to test it out but nothing showing in my console but there wasn't any error.

```
`const btn = document.getElementById('myNavbar');
```

btn.addEventListener('onclick', () => {
    console.log(123);
});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the event is `click`, not `onclick`. Use `onclick` when assigning to the *property* of the element (which you should generally try to avoid), eg

```
btn.onclick = () => console.log('foo');
```

but use the `'click'` *string* when adding a listener.

```js
const btn = document.getElementById('myNavbar');
btn.addEventListener('click', () => { console.log(123); });
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm fixed-top" id="myNavbar">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupported" aria-controls="navbarSupported" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <a href="#" class="navbar-brand" id="hello">Navbar</a>
  <!-- Nav content -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupport">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link active">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">About</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">Inspiration</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto navbar-right">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">Create</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you just want button to have shadow on hover you can just use css. element:hover{   }